# Django - lazy queries and efficiency

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Is there a way to speed this up?

```
section_list_active = Section.objects.all().filter(course=this_course,Active=True,filter(teacher__in=[this_teacher]).order_by('pk')
if section_list_active.count() > 0:
    active_section_id = section_list_active.first().pk
else:
    section_list = Section.objects.all().filter(course=this_course).filter(teacher__in=[this_teacher]).order_by('pk')
    active_section_id = section_list.first().pk
```

I know that the querysets aren't evaluated until they're used (the `.first().pk` bit?), so is there then no faster way to do this? If they weren't lazy, I could hit the DB for the whole list of sections, then just filter that set for ones with the property `Active`, but I'm not seeing how I can do this without hitting it twice (assuming that I have to go to the `else`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you are only intersted in the `Section` (or the corresponding `pk`), **Yes**. You can **order by the`Active` field** first:

```
active_section_id = Section.objects.filter(
    course=this_course,
    teacher=this_teacher
).order_by('-Active', 'pk').first().pk
```

or even a bit more elegant:

```
active_section_id = Section.objects.filter(
    course=this_course,
    teacher=this_teacher
).earliest('-Active', 'pk').pk
```

We thus will first order `Active` in descending order such that if there is a row with `Active=True`, then this one will be sorted at the top. Next we thus take the `.first()` object, and optionally take the `pk`.

In case there is no `Section` that satsifies the filter conditions, then `.first()` or `.earliest()` will return `None`, and this will thus result in an `AttributeError` when fetching the `pk` attribute.

> **Note**: typically fields are written in *lowercase*, so `active` instead of `Active`.

Comment: The first solution seems to work. `.earliest` throws an error that it only accepts two arguments at most, though.

Comment: I use lowercase for my foreign and M2M fields, and uppercase for strictly local ones. thought that was a convention?

Comment: @DeltaG: no the convention is typically that class members (like attributes, functions, are all lowercase, see PEP-8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: `TypeError at /gbook/1
earliest() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/gbook/1
Django Version:1.10
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
earliest() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
Exception Location: /Users/jgates/Desktop/SBGBookv2/gbsite/gbook/views.py in TransientIndexView, line 940
...
/Users/jgates/Desktop/SBGBookv2/gbsite/gbook/views.py in TransientIndexView
    active_section_id = Section.objects.filter(course=this_course,teacher=this_teacher).earliest('-Active', 'pk').pk#.order_by('-Active', 'pk').first().pk ...`

Comment: Looks like you use an old version of Django, the former version should work for older ones as well.